# multiple string replacement with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm using `sed` to replace string in a text file containing the following:

```
prop="distributed-${DEPLOY_ENV}.properties, database-${DEPLOY_ENV}.properties, compute-${DEPLOY_ENV}.properties"
```

using the following command in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
env=dev
sed \
-e "s/\${DEPLOY_ENV}/"${env}"/" \
```

But I get the following output; only the first occurrence of `DEPLOY_ENV` is replaced:

```
prop="distributed-dev.properties, database-${DEPLOY_ENV}.properties, compute-${DEPLOY_ENV}.properties"
```

How to replace all the occurrences instead of the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed "s/\${DEPLOY_ENV}/"${env}"/g"`

Add `/g` for global.

Comment: No, that's using the wrong quotes in the wrong places and so is exposing the whole script to shell for variable expansion (which is why you have to escape the `$`) and removes ALL quotes from around $env which would expose $env to the shell for word splitting, file name generation, etc. Always enclose scripts and strings in single quotes unless you have a very specific reason not to (which there isn't in this case) and you've got to quote your variables unless you **need** the shell to access them - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129767/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make the scope global by adding "g" so that you affect all occurrences of the match.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
env=dev
sed \
-e "s/\${DEPLOY_ENV}/"${env}"/g" \
```

and run the command as follows (where **text_file_with_envs.txt** represents your original file and **text_file_with_envs.txt.new** is your update file ):

```
$ ./sed-multi-repl.sh < ./text_file_with_envs.txt > ./text_file_with_envs.txt.new
```

this is the output of the cat on new file:

```
$ cat  text_file_with_envs.txt.new

prop="distributed-dev.properties, database-dev.properties, compute-dev.properties"
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
$ env=dev
$ sed 's/${DEPLOY_ENV}/'"$env"'/g' file
prop="distributed-dev.properties, database-dev.properties, compute-dev.properties"
```